# How to create a new File with the name of the current date

Tags: java, file, date

So I'm working on a project for work and one of the tasks I've been assigned is to create a button which, when pushed, creates a .txt file with the name of the current date and time. I know how to create a .txt file and I know how to get the current date. However, when I try to create a new file with the name of the date it creates an IOException.  Here is my code:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date = new Date();
String dateTxt = dateFormat.format(date) + ".txt";
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(dateTxt, "UTF-8");
```

The IOException is thrown there. However, if I replace dateTxt with something like "placeHolder.txt" it works fine and creates a new file. So I don't understand why it doesn't work with the String dateTxt. Please help.

Comment: Please post the exception.

Comment: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory

Comment: @DannySeaton Better to post additional info as an edit to the Question rather than as a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to change your SimpleDateFormat to something which outputs a valid file name:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss");
```

Answer (score 3):

`:` and `/` are special characters which you might want to escape while creating the file. Escaping these should allow you to create the file.

Comment: Windows doesn't allow filenames to contain any of `\ / : * ? " < > |`, so escaping those characters isn't enough, you have to replace them with something else.

Answer (score 1):

The [Answer by Venkat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37707883/642706) is correct, as is the [Answer by nvuono](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37707989/642706). But let's look at two issues: modern date-time classes and time zone handling.

## tl;dr

For UTC…

```
String now = Instant.now().truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.SECONDS ).toString().replace( "-" , "" ).replace( ":" , "" );
```

> 20160608T234748Z

For a local time zone (but left ambiguous by omitting the offset or time zone)…

```
String now = LocalDateTime.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ).truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.SECONDS ).toString().replace( "-" , "" ).replace( ":" , "" );
```

> 20160608T194748

For a local time zone including offset-from-UTC…

```
String now = OffsetDateTime.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ).truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.SECONDS ).toString().replace( "-" , "" ).replace( ":" , "" );
```

> 20160608T194748-0700

## Details

The classes shown in Question and other Answers are outmoded. The troublesome old date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java are supplanted in Java 8 and later by the java.time framework. Much of that functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in ThreeTen-Backport, and further adapted to Android in ThreeTenABP.

Also, time zone is not addressed.

If you want the current time in UTC, use [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html).

```
Instant instant = Instant.now();
```

You want whole seconds, so let's set the fractional second to zero by truncating to whole seconds..

```
Instant instant = Instant.now().truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.SECONDS );
```

The java.time classes use standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats by default when parsing/generating strings representing date-time values. The standard is in the year-month-date-hours-minutes-seconds ordering that yields chronological order when sorted alphabetically.

```
String output = instant.toString(); // 2016-06-08T23:47:48Z
```

Example output: `2016-06-08T23:47:48Z`. So need to replacing characters not allowed by various file systems on various operating systems. The comment by JonK lists some of those. As suggested by nvuono, one approach is to eliminate all punctuation marks. This minimizing of separators is known as the *basic* version in ISO 8601, with the standard using a `T` to separate the year-month-day from the hours-minutes-seconds.

One way to get to that basic format is deleting the punctuation inserted in the full version.

```
String output = instant.toString().replace( "-" , "" ).replace( ":" , "" );
```

Add a `.replace( "T" , "_" )` if you wish. The `T` can make the value harder to read when not using a sophisticated font. Some folks use no separators at all, but that makes the value difficult to discern to my eye.

I suggest you retain the `Z`, short for `Zulu` which means `UTC`. The meaning of a date-time is ambiguous without some indication of the time zone.

Or define your own formatting pattern.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "yyyyMMddTHHmmssX" ); // Or "yyyyMMdd_HHmmssX".
```

Use the `X` code to append the `Z` at the end if working with UTC.

The `Instant` class is a basic building block in java.time, not intended for formatting. Convert to a [`OffsetDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) to use a formatter. Specify the [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) you desire; here I use UTC itself via the constant [`ZoneOffset.UTC`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html#UTC).

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.ofInstant( instant , ZoneOffset.UTC );
```

Or, use the convenience method [`now`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#now-java.time.ZoneId-) to capture the current moment without going through a `Instant`. Remember to drop the fractional second.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.now( ZoneOffset.UTC ).truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.SECONDS );
```

The `OffsetDateTime` is for when you have only an [offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) but not a full [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone). A time zone is an offset *plus* a set of rules for handling anomalies such as [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time). If you prefer to use get a [wall-clock time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall-clock_time) for some locality, adjust into a time zone by applying a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( zoneId ).truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.SECONDS );
```

The `toString` method on `ZonedDateTime` includes both the offset-from-UTC (part of ISO 8601 standard) and also appends the name of the time zone in square brackets (an excellent idea, but not standard). If you really do not want to include time zone info, use a `DateTimeFormatter` as seen above. Or use a [`LocalDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) which purposely loses all time zone information.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.now( zoneId ).truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.SECONDS );
```

Delete the offending characters:

```
String output = ldt.toString().replace( "-" , "" ).replace( ":" , "" );
```